# PC crashing and changing boot order spontaneously

Tags: boot, crash

I've installed a software on my PC and after installation my PC crashed and changed boot order... i have 2x SSD and after i change boot order and wait a couple of minutes (sometimes seconds) after loging in system (Windows 10), PC just lag without blue screen and change boot order.

Comment: If possible, tell what software you installed.

Comment: Some game possibly with virus

Comment: In this case [restore windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/) to a previous point could help. Is it enabled on your Windows?

Comment: Nah..i didn't enable it, so now I'm trying to reinstall whole system with all drives, because reinstalling just windows without removing files didn't help at all...

Comment: Problem was in damaged secondary drive, when i tried to move/install files on it, PC crashed and changed boot order. Now i removed a SSD and everything works fine :)

Comment: Nice. It would be cool if you'd post the answer describing how you got to the solution and what tests you ran to be sure of that. It might be helpful to others ;)